# Change button Image and link in button 1 , when pressing another button (asp.net, #C, Web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When Im trying to press button 2, the image and http link in button 1 have to be changed ( to a youtube image and a youtube link).

(done in asp.net, C#, Web form)

Normally the image and http link in button 1 are empty.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
```

So it has to be something like this:

```
    if (button2 = clicked)
{
change image(youtube) and link(www.youtube.com)
}
```

after this is done I should be able to press button 1 and go to youtube.com

Currently I have:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Dit is de pagina als je ingelogd bent.
</div>
<div id="popupBoxOnePosition">
        <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
            <div class="popupBoxContent">
                <h3>Instellingen</h3>
                <p>Kies uit een van de volgende links.</p>

                <select style="width: 152px">
                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                <option value="Youtube">Youtube</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button_afsluiten" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;" Text="Afsluiten" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="48px" OnClientClick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');return false;"
```

Text="Button" />

the toggle visibility is to open a popupbox.
When I press button 1 in the popupbox, button 2 image and link has to be changed.

The Image it has changed to is:
The Image has to be: "data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="YouTube"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write your code in the click event of first button, something like that, write all fields you want

```
Protected void Button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    ImageButton2.Imageurl = "new image url1";
    ImageButton2.Text = "new text";
    // write rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: My program doesn't seem to find ImageButton2.Imageurl
Does my button 2 has to be called Imagebutton2?

Comment: yes your second button is that button. this is just demo code use it in your own way. you have to use image button for changing backgroung of button

Comment: it is not different from standered button.

Comment: I've editted my code. The 2 buttons and the rest of the code is now added in the main question. Can you take a look at it? It is a popupbox with a button in it (button2). When button 1 is empty it has to open the popupbox. When its added with somethink like youtube it has to change the button properties so it can open a youtube link instead of the popupbox.

Comment: where is image in your code ?, that you are trying to change, if it is dropdown list simply set `AutopostBack="true"` of it. nd write code in SelectedIndexChanging of dropdownlist.

Comment: Ive added the image link.

Comment: @Vince what Vikas has posted seems valid for your question.Have you applied it?

Comment: @Gotalove no not yet, cant seem to figure out what hes trying to say :S